# How to programmatically 'substitute' a ListView by a progress bar while it loads?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a simple ListView like this:

```
listView = view.findViewById(R.id.elements_list);
```

but I do not have access to the layout, so I cannot place a progress bar there. Can I make listView invisible and then make a `progressBar` appear in front of it? I can at least think on how to do it for the entire screen where `listView` is contained, but what if I want my `progressBar` to appear exactly in the middle (horizontally and vertically) of `listView`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you don't have access to the layout?

Comment: You can write code to hide the progressbar and show whenever it is necessary.

Comment: @p_anantha but I can't acess the layout, it is dinamically inserted depending on who inherits from this fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is in `Kotlin`, but it can be easily translate to `Java`.**

I think you can re-use what the `Android API` provides for free, to display a `Progress Circle indicator for example showing the idea that something is loading:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.app.Dialog
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        val progressBar = ProgressBar(this)

        progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        dialog.setContentView(progressBar)
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

The output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: but how do I insert the progressBar into the layout? How do I create a progressBar view and give it properties?

Comment: And in your example, the progressBar is put in the coordinates of the start of the listView. I can use math to calculate its center, but isn't there a way to insert in the center of the fragment? Since the listView matches dimensions with the fragment